# My Background Image Doesn't Show Up On Github

Tags: html, css, image, github, background

I have a sample landing page which I uploaded to gitHub. When I preview it on my computer with local files, everything works fine but I cannot see background image when I upload it to gitHub.

I've tried below codes to make it work but couldn't. [You can check gitHub respiratory from here if you wish.](https://github.com/tayfunilbakan/Landing-Page---Gudari-Ski-Resort) [And page from here.](https://tayfunilbakan.github.io/Landing-Page---Gudari-Ski-Resort/)

```
background-image: url(images\main.jpg);
background-image: url(/images/main.jpg);
background-image: url(../images/main.jpg);

background-image: url(images\main.jpg);
background-image: url(\images\main.jpg);
background-image: url(..\images\main.jpg);
```

Comment: Well.. You provided as with link to your repo and not github pages.

Comment: [link]https://tayfunilbakan.github.io/Landing-Page---Gudari-Ski-Resort/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.html` are you loading style using:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\styles.css">
```

But it should be:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Also, in styles.css you should load image using

```css
background-image: url(../images/main.jpg);
```

GitHub sites runs on Linux machines, that use in pathnames `/` instead `\` and Macs also uses `/`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but that didn't work out. I've applied your changes but nothing changed. Link to css file definitely works because everything except background image works fine. I just can't find why background image is not working.

Comment: Which browser are you using? On Mac Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome it works fine.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows. And just now it started working. Thanks for your helps!